# Content-Security-Policy with wildcard

Tags: url, wildcard, content-security-policy

I'm trying to set the Content-Security-Policy and I'm not able to use a wildcard to match the **second** part of a URL (test).

Examples:

https://example.test1.com

https://example.test2.com

https://example.testN.com

I tried all the following combinations unsuccessfully:

```
https://example.*.com

https://example.*.

https://example.*

https://example*
```

I'll appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported, you can only have wildcards in the leftmost DNS label, see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/CSP/Specification#Hostname_Wildcards